# Writing jama matrix to file

Tags: java, filewriter, printwriter, jama

I want to write a matrix to a file in java by using jama library.However, only a empty file is produced. I am using the code below. What can be wrong?

```
PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter("deneme.txt", "UTF-8");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    m3.print( writer,2,2);
```

Comment: I found the error. we need to flush the writer after printing the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

`writer` could be null when it comes to this line of code. Move the `m3.print(writer,2,2);` inside of the try block.

```
PrintWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = new PrintWriter("deneme.txt", "UTF-8");
    m3.print(writer, 2, 2);
} catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: the problem was not flushing the writer after writing. it was a silly question :(